# Не работает маршрутизация в angular 2

Tags: angular2, маршрутизация

У меня есть проект на angular 2 со следующей иерархией:

```
-AngularTest
    -app
        -projecttree.component.ts
        -projectcard.component.ts
        -app.component.ts
        -app.module.ts
        -...
    -node_modules
    -index.html
    -...
```

В app.module.ts имею следующий код:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }   from '@angular/http';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { ProjectTree }   from './projecttree.component';
import { ProjectCard }   from './projectcard.component';

import {ProjectService} from './services/project.service';

const appRoutes: Routes =[
    { path: '', component: ProjectTree},
    { path: 'project', component: ProjectCard},
    { path: '**', component: ProjectTree}
];



@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent, ProjectTree, ProjectCard ],
    providers:    [ ProjectService ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

В index.html первым пунктом в `<head>` стоит :

```
<base href="/AngularTest/" />
```

В шаблон главного компонента (app.component.ts) вставил router-outlet

```
<div>
    <h1 id="shapka">Статичная шапка</h1>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>`
```

В результате:

```
localhost/AngularTest/ - работает, выдаёт projecttree компонент
localhost/AngularTest/project - ошибка 404
любой другой путь, отличный от "/AngularTest/" - ошибка 404
```

Пробовал различные комбинации значений `<base>` и `Routes` - пока безрезультатно.

### UPDATE

Приложение пишу и тестирую в WebStorm, полный url до главного компонента:

```
http://localhost:63342/AngularTest/
```

Comment: не нужно писать в пути название проекта. localhost/ localhost/project и в base уберите. Оставьте только /

Comment: c <base href = "/"> при переходе на localhost - ошибка 404, а при localhost/AngularTest - страницу видит, но не может подтянуть библиотеки.
(index):14 GET http://localhost:63342/systemjs.config.js и прочие

Comment: Очень странно. Попробуйте создать через cli проект. https://cli.angular.io/

Comment: а что у Вас за сервер? Ваш сервер должен обращаться только к index.html

Comment: и конечно же если Вы напишите http://localhost:63342/AngularTest он и будет искать этот файл AngularTest, потому что отработает роут сервера, а не html5  роутинг

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так и не нашёл причину этой ошибки. 
Создал новый проект в том же WebStorm, но с помощью angular-cli. Всё работает отлично. Спасибо за ответы, вопрос закрыт.